# compressibility of cold atoms in optical lattices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, cold-atoms

The compressibility of cold bosons in an optical lattice is defined as $\kappa = \frac{\partial \langle n\rangle}{\partial \mu}$, where $\langle n\rangle$ is the density and $\mu$ is the chemical potential. It can also write as $\kappa = \langle n^2\rangle-\langle n\rangle^2$ at zero temperature. How to prove they are equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may start from the density matrix $\rho$ of the grand canonical ensemble (assuming $k_BT=1$ as the unit of energy),
$$\rho=Z^{-1}e^{-H+\mu n},$$
where $Z=\text{Tr}\,e^{-H+\mu n}$ is the partition function. Then $\langle n\rangle$ and $\langle n^2\rangle$ are defined by tracing with the density matrix
$$\langle n\rangle=\text{Tr}\,n\rho\text{, and }\langle n^2\rangle=\text{Tr}\,n^2\rho.$$
Based on the above setup, it is easy to verify that
$$\begin{split}
\kappa =&\partial_\mu \langle n\rangle\\
=&\partial_\mu\frac{\text{Tr}\,n e^{-H+\mu n}}{\text{Tr}\,e^{-H+\mu n}}\\
=&\frac{\text{Tr}\,n^2 e^{-H+\mu n}}{\text{Tr}\,e^{-H+\mu n}}-\frac{(\text{Tr}\,n e^{-H+\mu n})^2}{(\text{Tr}\,e^{-H+\mu n})^2}\\
=&\langle n^2\rangle-\langle n\rangle^2.
\end{split}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the derivation. I have a confusion. For finite temperature, following your derivation, one gets $\kappa =\beta (\langle n^2\rangle-\langle n\rangle^2)$. Then why for zero temperature one can set $\beta =1$? Thank you!

Comment: @rain Because the compressibility is actually defined as $\kappa=k_B T\partial_\mu\langle n\rangle$, the factor $k_B T$ is required to make $\kappa$ a dimensionless constant. So $\kappa=\langle n^2\rangle-\langle n\rangle^2$ is well-defined at zero temperature.